# How to call make a variable a callable function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I have a code in which the user chooses the function he wants to execute. There is no definite amount of functions as the functions may increase in the future. I am storing the value fetched from the User input into a variable. I want to make the variable callable.

```
functions = ['add','sub','mul']
a = 10
b = 5

x = input('Choose a function : ')

def add():
    print(a+b)
def mul():
    print(a*b)
def sub():
    print(a-b)

x()
```

I want the variable 'x' to be called and executed as a function.

Comment: You can assign functions to variables. `x=add` Then you can call x as a function. `x(1,2)`

Answer (score 1):

I think, correct solution for this will be [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). Also it gives you some flexibility to give different string keywords for functions. Code:

```
def add(a, b):
    print(a + b)


def mul(a, b):
    print(a * b)


def sub(a, b):
    print(a - b)


functions = {
    'add': add,
    'sub': sub,
    'mul': mul
}

a = 10
b = 5

x = input('Choose a function : ')

if x not in functions:
    print(f"Function \"{x}\" is not defined.")
else:
    functions[x](a, b)
```

But if you think that it's 100% neccesary to call function by string name, you can get reference to function from [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals):

```
func = globals().get(x, None)
if not x:
    print(f"Function \"{x}\" is not defined.")
else:
    func(a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

I notice you don't use `functions`, but you're on to something there. It should be a dictionary of names to functions

```
def add():
    ...

functions = {'add': add,'sub': sub, 'mul': mul}

choice = input('Choose a function : ')
f = functions[choice]

f()
```

Answer (score 0):

`eval()` could work for you, just know that it allows arbitrary code execution, so be careful how you allow values to get passed to it.

E.g.:

```
$ python
Python 3.7.2 (default, Feb 12 2019, 08:15:36) 
[Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def a():
...     print('a')
... 
>>> def b():
...     print('b')
... 
>>> func = eval('a')
>>> func()
a
>>> func = eval('b')
>>> func()
b
>>>
```

Or with the user selection step:

```
# ...
>>> func_choice = input('Choose a function: ')
Choose a function: a
>>> func = eval(func_choice)
>>> func()
a
>>>
```

Comment: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: While this technically works, it's a bad idea in general to use `eval`.

Comment: Is it right to use eval() when there is user input involved?

Comment: It's potentially risky, especially in the way I've shown here.  But if you trust the user and validate the input, it can be okay to use, especially where you need a lot of flexibility (e.g., while under development).

Comment: @ayushsingh, you can easily replace `eval(func_name)` with `globals()[func_name]()` which will be more "secure".

Comment: @OlvinRoght , I'll go with the globals() , Thanks for you help, cheers :)

Comment: @ayushsingh, I recommend you to proceed with dict instead, cause it's just better ;)